# asyn example calling multiple method

Tags: .net, async-await, c#-5.0

I  am learning the async programming, i am not sure if i am going in the right direction. I want to call multiple method async but  from what i read asyn should start from top level follow to the lowest level. But at the top level when i do asyn method the compiler complaining cannot wait string.

```
    public static async void Method()
    {
        var classdemoAsyn = new DemoAsyn();
        var t = await classdemoAsyn.DoSomeImportantWork("Start ").Result;
    } 

public class DemoAsyn
{
    public async Task<string> DoSomeImportantWork(string strDoSomeWork)
    {
        strDoSomeWork = strDoSomeWork + " (1) Enter => so some important work";
        Console.WriteLine("**********Enter => so some important work******");
        var t = await SomeComplexOperation(strDoSomeWork);
        Console.WriteLine("***********End Do some important work***********");
        return t;
    }

    public Task<string> SomeComplexOperation(string StrDoSomeComplexWork)
    {
        string str =StrDoSomeComplexWork + "Enter => very very complex work";
        Console.WriteLine(str);
        return Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {return str; });
    }

}
```

Comment: What kind of app is this (UI or ASP.NET)? Also, is your "work" CPU-bound or I/O?

Comment: You get the compiler error because you are `await`ing the `Result` of the task not the task itself. Remove `.Result` and that error should go away although there are other issues with your code.

Comment: it a small console app, @StephenCleary. I just start learning async all what i want to achive write few method asyn start from top level to bottom level.

Comment: @DanielKelley i thought when access the result at the top level to avoid deadlock the method should be async with an await function?

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is because you're using *both* `.Result` and `await` at the same time (as already pointed out by Daniel Kelley).

A common simple approach to use `async` in console applications is to have a top-level `async Task` method and synchronously wait on it in your `Main()` method (this is pretty much the only place where `Wait()` or `Result` make sense in an async-using code), e.g.:

```
void Main()
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
}
```

Another option would be to use [Stephen Cleary's `AsyncContext.Run()`](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-console-programs.html).